# Sennheiser passive omnidirectional antennas

Tags: wireless

We have one EM-XSW 2 and one EM-XSW rack-mounted wireless receivers which are experiencing dropouts in a large cafeteria because they need to be located in a closet in a older building with stone, heavy masonry and steel-girder construction. Our experiences with network WiFi coverage in this building has forced us to over-provision our WAPs for adequate service, and I'm concerned that the wireless receivers in this closet are being affected by this building's construction. I asked a reputable audio company if the Sennheiser G4 ASA 214-UHF Active Antenna Splitter and passive A1031-U omnidirectional antennas would be an applicable setup for providing improved reception, but they said it would not work.

Can the Sennheiser passive A1031-U antennas be used alone without the splitter, and if so, do we need two antennas per receiver (total of four antennas?)

Is there a maximum cable length specified between the receiver and the A1031-U antennas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question related to RF operation not sound design. Please address with the manufacturer.

Comment: Is there a SE site that is more appropriate for my question? I contacted the manufacturer a week ago, but have heard nothing back.

Comment: did the audio company say why it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sennheiser wrote back with this answer:

*If you have the XSW 2 with the external antennas then the ASA 214 should work for antenna distro but it just wouldn't power the units like it would for the g4 units but nothing is stopping it from working for the antennas. Also, if you wanted to use the antennas stand alone with out the distro those would work as well. Essentially the antennas and distro are both wide band and use the bnc connections so if you need more distance/coverage this would be a good choice.*

I think I will choose the Active Antenna Splitter ("distro") which lets me connect up to four receivers using two omni or directional antennae. We have older G3 & G4 wireless rigs we can use with the splitter, and I can see several use cases coming up.